# Troubleshooting Ubuntu 22.10 Hard Crash with cool system and no heavy load

Tags: boot, kernel, crash, reboot, temperature

I am running Ubuntu 22.10 on my Home Desktop machine.

My system is crashing at what appears to be random intervals, with no immediate cause I can think of. Without any warning or any particular action that could cause it, the computer just shuts down and reboots, like when someone presses the "Reset" button on the case/BIOS.

These are my sensors immediately after one of these crashes:

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +58.6°C  
Tccd1:        +46.2°C  
Tccd2:        +44.5°C  

nvme-pci-2200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +46.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +46.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +56.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

nvme-pci-2300
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +56.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +89.8°C)
                       (crit = +94.8°C)

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +42.0°C  

nct6797-isa-0a20
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:            1.26 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:          1000.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in2:            3.33 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in3:            3.31 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in4:            1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:          160.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:          672.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in7:            3.33 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in8:            3.30 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in9:            1.84 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in10:           0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
in11:         456.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in12:           1.10 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:         680.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:           1.53 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:            0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:         1086 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:            0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:            0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:          699 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan6:          969 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan7:         1422 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:        +47.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = CPU diode
CPUTIN:        +41.0°C  (high = +108.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:       +45.0°C  (high = +108.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:      -128.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:       +62.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:        -2.0°C    sensor = thermistor
Virtual_TEMP:  +58.0°C  
Virtual_TEMP:  +59.0°C  
Virtual_TEMP:  +58.0°C  
Virtual_TEMP:  +58.0°C  
TSI0_TEMP:     +58.5°C  
intrusion0:   ALARM
intrusion1:   ALARM
beep_enable:  disabled

nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +45.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +84.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +45.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +48.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```

This is my `journalctl -b -1 -e` output, showing that nothing got logged before the crash/reboot:

```
mag 29 10:49:14 bwian-MS-7C35 gnome-shell[2742]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
mag 29 10:49:14 bwian-MS-7C35 gnome-shell[2742]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
mag 29 10:50:04 bwian-MS-7C35 gnome-shell[2742]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x5650fd7ec680] is on because it needs an allocation.
mag 29 10:50:04 bwian-MS-7C35 gnome-shell[2742]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x5650fdea1ba0] is on because it needs an allocation.
mag 29 10:50:04 bwian-MS-7C35 gnome-shell[2742]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x5651001067c0] is on because it needs an allocation.
mag 29 10:50:25 bwian-MS-7C35 gnome-shell[2742]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x5651001067c0] is on because it needs an allocation.
mag 29 10:52:10 bwian-MS-7C35 gnome-shell[2742]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x5650fd7ec680] is on because it needs an allocation.
mag 29 10:52:10 bwian-MS-7C35 gnome-shell[2742]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x5650ffdcd1f0] is on because it needs an allocation.
mag 29 10:52:10 bwian-MS-7C35 gnome-shell[2742]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x565109af6f60] is on because it needs an allocation.
mag 29 10:53:08 bwian-MS-7C35 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2742]: Microsoft Teams - Preview1, Impossible to lookup icon for 'Microsoft Teams - Preview1_13-panel' in path /tmp/.org.chr>
mag 29 10:53:08 bwian-MS-7C35 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2742]: unable to update icon for Microsoft Teams - Preview1
mag 29 10:53:15 bwian-MS-7C35 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2742]: Microsoft Teams - Preview1, Impossible to lookup icon for 'Microsoft Teams - Preview1_14-panel' in path /tmp/.org.chr>
mag 29 10:53:15 bwian-MS-7C35 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2742]: unable to update icon for Microsoft Teams - Preview1
mag 29 10:55:01 bwian-MS-7C35 CRON[29178]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
mag 29 10:55:01 bwian-MS-7C35 CRON[29179]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
mag 29 10:55:01 bwian-MS-7C35 CRON[29178]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

My `kern.log` also showing nothing I find to be relevant:

```
May 29 09:48:09 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [ 2121.745635] kauditd_printk_skb: 7 callbacks suppressed
May 29 09:48:09 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [ 2121.745638] audit: type=1400 audit(1685346489.868:116): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" pro
file="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oosplash" pid=18136 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 29 09:48:09 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [ 2121.767162] audit: type=1400 audit(1685346489.888:117): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" pro
file="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=18140 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 29 09:48:12 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [ 2124.796003] audit: type=1400 audit(1685346492.916:118): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-soffi
ce" pid=18143 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 29 09:48:12 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [ 2124.822358] audit: type=1400 audit(1685346492.944:119): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-soffi
ce//gpg" pid=18143 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 29 09:48:12 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [ 2124.846377] audit: type=1400 audit(1685346492.968:120): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" pro
file="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=18182 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.19.0-42-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-019) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-3ubuntu1) 12.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutil
s for Ubuntu) 2.39) #43-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Apr 18 18:21:28 UTC 2023 (Ubuntu 5.19.0-42.43-generic 5.19.17)
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-42-generic root=UUID=ea1660b0-ea10-41d0-baa8-bc942fb21e02 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] signal: max sigframe size: 1776
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009d81fff] usable
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000009d82000-0x0000000009ffffff] reserved
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a000000-0x000000000a1fffff] usable
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a200000-0x000000000a20ffff] ACPI NVS
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a210000-0x00000000cacb0fff] usable
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cacb1000-0x00000000cb0a8fff] reserved
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cb0a9000-0x00000000cb10cfff] ACPI data
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cb10d000-0x00000000ccc0cfff] ACPI NVS
May 29 11:04:23 bwian-MS-7C35 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ccc0d000-0x00000000cdbfefff] reserved
```

Additional notes:

- There is nothing I can do to reproduce the issue
- Temperature looks fine, thermal paste was changed last year and I am using a performant Noctua NX-15 cooler. The PC is free from any dust.
- The system is up-to-date
- Sometimes the issue has been correlated to heavy load, both on the GPU *or* the CPU
- ...But stress testing both did not reproduce the crash
- Memtest did not find any issues
- I also used some benchmark and stresstest programs to try to put some load on the PSU, but they lacked wizard or automated tests and I am not sure if I did it correctly, i would be glad if someone provided me with some way of testing my PSU
- Logs look clear, like the system couldn't write anything in time before rebooting

My suspect is that the PSU could be failing, or the motherboard, but I was never able to be sure of what the problem is.

How can I ensure what is the failing hardware?

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace a working PSU to check if Ubuntu still crashes.
2. If you don't have one or can't borrow one, install Windows 10 for a dual-boot setup. There are more options for easy-to-use stress test programs on Windows. Run them to see if Windows crashes. If it runs smoothly, you can almost rule out a hardware problem.
3. Switch between the Nouveau and proprietary GPU drivers, and also try different versions.
4. Consider trying Ubuntu 20.04 or using desktop environments other than Cinnamon, such as KDE, Xfce, or LXDE, to see if the problem persists.